# Mark (or exclude) files in project tool window in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Does anybody know of a way to mark files in project tool window with color or something? I'm mostly interested in classes.

I need this in my practice projects when I replace one class with another, but still do not want to loose original implementation, since it already sits logically where it should.

I know IntelliJ has File Exclusion option. Is there something similar in Android Studio? I'm currently using version 2.3.2

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the trivial solution I found is to annotate old classes with `@Depricated` which would result them to be strike-out in Project Tool window.